# Approving list items based on the selected list filter web parts's value

Tags: sharepoint-online, approval-process

I have a list and a list filter web part in the page. The list filter web part filters the list by `Created by` column.
After filtering, I want the list to be approved.
The filtered rows should be approved. Is it possible by using javascript code?

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are attached this list to approval workflow.
then when item created in current list the approval workflow will create the item in task list.
This item title will be having value with current list item.

Get the task list by title as per current item.
Update TaskOutcome, status and mark fields as per Approve or Reject.